# angular 7 rxjs nested interface how to take only the nested array?

Tags: angular, typescript, interface, nested, rxjs

I have this interface with nested array inside:

```
import { IEmitente } from './ICustomer';

export interface IAccounts {
        current_page: number;
        data: ICustomer[];
        first_page_url: string;
        from: number;
        last_page: number;
        last_page_url: string;
        next_page_url: string;
        path: string;
        per_page: number;
        prev_page_url: string;
        to: number;
        total: number;
}
```

the customer interface is like this:

```
export interface ICustomer {
id: number;
name: string;
federalId: string;
firstBuy: date;
balance: number;
}
```

I have this http get method on service:

```
getContas(identific,search,page?): Observable<IAccounts[]> {
    return this.httpClient.get<IAccounts[]>(`${this.BASE_URL}/getContas?identific=${identific}&search=${search}&page=${page}`)
  }
```

the observable is look like this:

```
{current_page: 1, data: Array(15), first_page_url: "https://web.gruposol.com.br/endpoint/api/getContas?page=1", from: 1, last_page: 19, …}
current_page: 1
data: (15) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
first_page_url: "https://address/api/getContas?page=1"
from: 1
last_page: 19
last_page_url: "https://address/api/getContas?page=19"
next_page_url: "https://address/api/getContas?page=2"
path: "https://address/api/getContas"
per_page: 15
prev_page_url: null
to: 15
total: 275
__proto__: Object
```

how can I get only data (customers) part from observable using rxjs?
I need some like this:
on a variable `customers:ICustomer[] = [];`
I'd like to receive only data array from observable. How can I do that?
currently my ngOnInit method is like this:

```
  ngOnInit() {
     this.AlvosService.getContas(this.identific, this.search)
       .subscribe((response) => { console.log(response)} ),
        (error) => { console.log(error); };

  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a **Pipe**, and **Map** nested values

```
this.AlvosService.getContas(this.identific, this.search)
          .pipe(
            switchMap((accounts) => accounts.map((account) => account.data))
          )
          .subscribe((customers) => { console.log(customers) }),
          (error) => { console.log(error); }
```

*Note: you better not use variables starting with Capital letters, as in **AlvosService**, that is bad practice*

Comment: I already tryed this, but once I refer accounts.data I receive this error: Property 'data' does not exist on type 'IAccounts[]

Comment: i'm sorry pressed the enter to soon: Property 'data' does not exist on type 'IAccounts[]

Comment: @HeberPaesFomin Sorry, my bad, I corrected my answer, should work now

Comment: I hope you don't bother with my ignorance, but, you started with this.accounts. it means I have to put your suggested code on subscribe after assignment of this.accounts?

Comment: the way you suggested before, the error only appear on compiling process, but on chrome's console shows only what I need, besides the error.

Comment: @HeberPaesFomin It was the variable I used to test your code (: It works the same. Changed it back anyway

Comment: in addition to that solution you should have changed getContas method. As current code says response should be converted to `IAccounts[]` which is not true. change it to `{data: IAccounts[]}` at least and it will be ok and your code will run with no problems. But still the right way would be to create interface that is truly returned from backend and cast response to that interface

Comment: with this way I got this error: ERROR TypeError: accounts.map is not a function. About the last comment you made, sometimes I will need to get whole object IAccounts[], for example, when I need to paginate. The field data: of interface is not related to IAccounts, but,  is related to ICustomer interface (look the example above). I just want to take the data: ICustomer on a variable, to take out only the array of customers.

Comment: @HeberPaesFomin about the error, can you upload a sample to StackBlitz? About the pagination, I am not sure what do you mean. Do you need multiple customers arrays or one that is a merge of all?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
this.AlvosService.getContas(this.identific, this.search)
          .pipe(
            mergeMap(accounts => accounts),
            map((account: IAccounts) => account.data),
            toArray()
          )
          .subscribe((customers) => { console.log(customers)} ),
           (error) => { console.log(error); };
```

Since your http call is returning an array of `IAccounts`, you'll need to `flatten` the array, `map` the data and `zip` it into an array again.

Comment: with this way I got this error: ERROR TypeError: You provided an invalid object where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.

Comment: Sounds fishy. Try with mergeMap((accounts => of(accounts))

Answer (score 0):

I figuered out what the error was.
If you look the response above you'll see that the response object was not an array.
The problem was the brackets on get method on service. Instead of `<IAccounts[]>` should be `<IAccounts>` only. So, changed the method like this:

```
getContas(identific,search,page?): Observable<IAccounts> {
    return this.httpClient.get<IAccounts>(`${this.BASE_URL}/getContas?identific=${identific}&search=${search}&page=${page}`)
  }
```

It works!
thanks so much for your helps.

Comment: First I am happy you figured it out (: Second, correct me if I am wrong, buf the error has nothing to do with your first question. The question was how to get a nested array, and the answer was correct. The type interface typo is a different issue. Calling a function “getContacts” that returns a single contact is really strange.

Comment: You are not wrong. Your first answer was perfect. I used that. But like I told, was a compile error because the type was wrong. Thank you very much for your help. The getContacts doesn't receive a single contact, but the api wraps the data collection with paginate information, so, I receive an object only with an array inside with data.